# google places api INVALID_REQUEST

Tags: json, google-places-api

```
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/details/json?reference=CmRYAAAAciqGsTRX1mXRvuXSH2ErwW-jCINE1aLiwP64MCWDN5vkXvXoQGPKldMfmdGyqWSpm7BEYCgDm-iv7Kc2PF7QA7brMAwBbAcqMr5i1f4PwTpaovIZjysCEZTry8Ez30wpEhCNCXpynextCld2EBsDkRKsGhSLayuRyFsex6JA6NPh9dyupoTH3g&key=AddYourOwnKeyHere
```

In this request url i needs to know what is the "reference" contains. Actually that is the Search text needs to be passed to api. but i have used the encoding the string before sending to api call like this

```
private String getPlacesUrl(String query) {

    try {
        query = "input=" + URLEncoder.encode(query, "utf-8");
    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e1) {
        e1.printStackTrace();
    }
return query;
   }
```

but still it is sending the query as normal encoded string like "London".

How to achieve the reference like encoding what given in Google api request. can any one help me...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

while searching places in Autocomplete search we should send the request to get the Places Details url. your Structure should be similar to this:

```
private String getPlaceDetailsUrl(String ref){

    // reference of place
    String reference = "reference="+ref;

    // Sensor enabled
    String sensor = "sensor=false";

    // Building the parameters to the web service
    String parameters = reference+"&"+sensor+"&"+mKey;

    // Output format
    String output = "json";

    // Building the url to the web service
    String url = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/details/"+output+"?"+parameters;

    return url;
}
```

For More details refer this site as base. It's pretty good.
[google Places autocomplete api](http://wptrafficanalyzer.in/blog/adding-google-places-autocomplete-api-as-custom-suggestions-in-android-search-dialog/)

Answer (score 0):

Use this following link.There are some examples.maybe it will help you.

http://www.w3docs.com/learn-javascript/places-autocomplete.html